# PHP Function - what am I missing?

Tags: php, function, return

SOLVED - USER ERROR - helps if one declares a variable doesn't it...

Help,

I have the following PHP Function code:

```
function new_respondent() {
    global $link;
    $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO trespondent_bps (code) VALUES (uuid());");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);
    $respondent_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($proc);
    mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
    mysqli_clean_connection($link);
    return($code);
}
```

For the life of me, it's adding the UUID into the database no problems at all - but it's not returning it so I can use it in the code - what am I missing/ doing wrong!!!

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Comment: I take it the id field is set to AUTO INCREMENT? $code isnt set to anything either, if you want the func to return the id, shouldnt it be return($respondent_id)?

Comment: YUP - as below - what a NUMPTY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a variable `$code` that is undefined.

```
function new_respondent() {
    global $link;
    $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO trespondent_bps (code) VALUES (uuid());");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);
    $respondent_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($proc);
    mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
    mysqli_clean_connection($link);
    return($respondent_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function new_respondent() {
    global $link;
    $code = uniqid();

    $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO trespondent_bps (code) VALUES (" . $code .");");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);
    $respondent_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($proc);
    mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
    mysqli_clean_connection($link);
    return($code);
}
```

note that i didn't escape it since it's safe

Answer (score 1):

you are forgetting the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($code);`

```
    function new_respondent() {
        global $link;
        $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO trespondent_bps (code) VALUES (uuid());");
        mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);
        $respondent_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($code);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($proc);
        mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
        mysqli_clean_connection($link);
        return($code);
    }
```